# Error with permissions sending mail with Apache + PHP without changing permission to 777

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

I cant get sendmail to work from apache+php unless I change the permission to 777 for /var/spool/clientmqueue.

Ownership of /var/spool/clientmqueue

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 smmsp mail 4096 Jul 19 11:50 clientmqueue
```

I've messed with user groups for smmsp and apache.

```
id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),12(mail)

id mail
uid=12(mail) gid=12(mail) groups=12(mail),48(apache)
```

SELinux is disabled

```
getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
getsebool: SELinux is disabled
```

In the maillog if I set the folder permission to 770

```
NOQUEUE: SYSERR(apache): can not write to queue directory
/var/spool/clientmqueue/ (RunAsGid=48, required=12): Permission denied
```

No mail will be sent and I would get an error from php.

If I set the folder to 0777 then instead I would get this in the maillog

```
dangerous permissions=40776 on queue directory /var/spool/clientmqueue/
```

But php would send out mails fine.

Is it possible to get it working with 0770 and apache being read in group for mail. I know the error is getting apaches main GID 48, but it also shares group 12.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This one did the trick for me. I had other errors before hitting this one on Ubuntu machine. Let me share that in case someone else runs into them. I was getting 
NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue-client/): Permission denied.

```
usermod -a -G smmsp www-data
chmod 770 /var/spool/mqueue-client     (don't use 775, it gives dangerous permission error in the log)
service apache2 restart (this is required for the above to take effect)
Now sending email gives a different error.
- NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not write to queue directory /var/spool/mqueue-client/
- chmod 4555 /usr/sbin/sendmail
- Above command fixed the email issue. => didn't see any error in the mail.log this time.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem identically today (and came here looking for an answer).

I eventually found [this overview](http://shebangme.blogspot.ie/2009/12/sendmail-runasuser-unknown-user-smmsp.html); running the following command from that list fixed the problem for me:

```
chmod 4555 /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

This sets the [setuid special mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on the sendmail binary, presumably allowing Apache to send mails as the mail user.

(I restarted both the apache and sendmail daemons after running that, though I'm unsure which of those actually needed restarting)

I'm still highly curious as to what *caused* this issue in the first place however ...